# Read parameter using rewriting engine

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have this type of url :

> domain.com/articles/title

And i want to rewrite this url in :

> domaic.com/articles.php?id=title

I use this rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ articles.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I can show the page articles.php but i try to read value of id's variable with **$_GET['id']** but is empty.

Thank in advance for your reply

Comment: RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z]+)$ articles.php?id=$1 [QSA,L] for strings Lower and upper case. If You want numbers just RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)$ articles.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]. You can also use \w for word \d for digit but use + for more then one char

Comment: What  folder  is your htaccess file located in?

Comment: Is located outside of www folder, I should located it in the same folder of the php file?